# how to install mono xsp4 and fastcgi-mono-server4

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, mono

Quick question - I'm on Debian squeeze, running nginx fine and installed mono fine. Now I want to host a .net4 web application and as I understand it I'll need fastcgi-mono-server4 (and xsp4 when testing it out) - where do I get these packages?

I tried `apt-get install fastcgi-mono-server4` and same for `mono-xsp4-base`.  When I did `apt-get searchpkg mono` I couldn't see anything relating to xsp4 or fastcgi server4.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (sorry for the rushed question)

Regards,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha!  Answer was in the question - I'm running Debian Squeeze.  Should have been on a higher version of Debian (wheezy).  Installed wheezy and checked `apt-cache search xsp` and sure enough there was xsp4.

Cheers,

James